# Message shown after text written

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, textbox, textchanged

I have a `textbox` that after I write text in that textbox I want to show a message ("you have typed text"). However I want to show this *WITHOUT* `button_click` event. I thought a textchanged event would work (using WPF). However I cannot write text before message shows.

I feel like I need a `on_click` event or something like this? However how would I show the message in just that textbox AFTER the text is written ? So only time I see that message is after I type text in that textbox.

Comment: Use Javascript onBlur event.

Comment: Sorry, missed reading WPF part. Try WPF TextBox.LostFocus

Comment: @BenjaminJones VB.NET means nothing.  ASP is often developed in VB.NET, as are half a dozen other major platforms.  You need to be more clear that you're talking about WPF.

Comment: Mihir TextBox.LostFocus works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how your textbox definition should look like

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="250,1,0,0" x:Name="T1"  
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" LostFocus="T1_LostFocus"  />
```

Show the messagebox in the T1_lostFocus

Answer (score 0):

go to the text box property and under the properties there will be a lightning bolt(events) click on it and click on the TextChanged property, so you will have:

```
private void textbox_TextChanged (blah, blah)
{
 timer1.enabled = true;
 timer1.interval = 1000
}
private void timer1_tick (blah, blah)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Text");
}
```

when the user changes text, it will trigger a timer, and after not typing for 1 second it will trigger a message